# Angular list loading in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, browser

I have created a jewelry catalog in Angular.js There are 2500 items in the JSON file. and the items are also linked to an image directory. The list is only populating  in Firefox. It will not populate in Chrome, Microsoft edge and Microsoft internet explorer. I need to resolve this issue

HTML page :

```
<!doctype html> 
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <title>Angular Demo</title> 
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/app.js"></script> <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div class="bg"> 
            <div class="main" ng-view></div> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: could you add some relevant code here?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Demo</title>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
 <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: don't think there is anything relevant to what you are asking..it just contains an html page which is having `ng-view` in it..

Comment: @AsifAli There is a link to edit the question. It's better to put the code in the question. Also, as Pankaj said, the code you pasted is not enough for us to help. Ideally you could try to reproduce the problem in a snippet or in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g03uzr2/)

Comment: I want to say pls edit your question add your code in controllers.js ?